# how to remove Xpad window decoration in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, notes

I installed xpad to use as sticky notes in ubuntu 12.04. However, xpad opens up like a normal app with window decorations as does not look like a sticky note at all. is there a way to customise that? The toolbars do not show up for Xpad in Ubuntu 12.04.
Also, are there any other sticky note apps which behave like the windows 7 sticky note or KDE sticky note which work in ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any note that you have created, right-click ---> View ---> un-tick Window Decorations.